# Usage of "Would it be" vs "Will it be" vs "Is it"

Tags: grammar, questions

> **Would it be** ok if I look at the sun wearing sunglasses?
>
> **Is it** ok if I look at the sun wearing sunglasses?

Which one is correct?

Comment: If you say *would it...* it sounds as though you are asking for permission, not asking whether it is bad for you - so the second one is better. By the way, in the sentence with *would you*, *look* should be in the past tense.

Comment: @Minty thx "will it be" should be considered ?

Answer (score 1):

**All of the above.** There's essentially zero recognised difference between the three. At the very least, no native speaker would ever think about what exact verb form someone else used; however, one might find "would" constructions occurring more often in more formal settings, just subconsciously.